# Is there any way to use django for business application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to build business application with database and some extensions that need to work on client side. I know there are technologies created for this purpose like silverlight, but django models and admin make working with database a lot easier. Extensions I need to add should work on windows machines and have full access to them. I know this violates browser security, but maybe there is any way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned — there is technologies, built for this: Java, Silverlight, Flash/Flex. But Django is for server-side development only.

Actually, I don't see any reason in moving some part of logic to client, but business requirements are usually tough thing, so look to one of the above technologies.

So, when you'll start making your app, look at someting like http://django-rest-framework.org/ in order to make it compatible with non-browser clients.

Comment: Maybe i could use java applets or something else with django for this purpose?

Comment: Definitely you can, Django doesn't care, who's sending requests: browser, java applet, mobile app... Updated answer a little bit